# MoveIt! move_group plan function not returning

Tags: ros, moveit, move-group

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong that would cause this issue. I originally was just using the move() function but that wasn't returning either. I thought it had something to do with just running this in rviz and not really executing anything.

So I switched to plan() instead but found I was having the same issue. I've attached the barebones I've boiled this down to:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "move_group_interface_demo");
    ros::NodeHandle node;

    move_group_interface::MoveGroup group("arm");

    ros::Rate rate(1);
    while (node.ok()){
        group.setRandomTarget();

        moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::Plan  plan;

        ROS_INFO("Planning");

        if(group.plan(plan)) {
            ROS_INFO("Planning Successful");
        }
        else {
            ROS_WARN("Planning failed!");
        }
        rate.sleep();
    }

    ROS_INFO("DONE");

    ros::waitForShutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

Like I said, I'm sure it's a careless mistake that I'm not seeing. I'm using the demo.launch file created using the MoveIt! Setup Assistant. I see the plan being visualized in RViz after the planning is initiated? But the function doesn't return in this simple node.

In the terminal I see "Planning" being printed but neither the successful or failure messages print after that.

Also, I can use the planners in MoveIt! just fine inside of RViz to "plan and execute".

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/91491/moveit!-move_group-plan-function-not-returning/) by [skiesel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2807/skiesel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 549 on 2013-10-16

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-10-17**:
Perfect question! You'd better ask this at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/moveit-users, and I'm sure you'll get a quick answer there.

**Comment by [skiesel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2807/skiesel/) on 2013-10-17**:
Thanks Martin, I'll repost this to their google-group.

**Comment by [Damon](https://answers.ros.org/users/22801/damon/) on 2015-06-24**:
Thanks for the question (and the answer) skiesel. Was useful. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After a goodnight's sleep it hit me. **THREADS**. Ugh.

http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning#Multi-threaded_Spinning

```
ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
spinner.start();
```

---

Originally posted by [skiesel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2807/skiesel/) with karma: 549 on 2013-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravipr009](https://answers.ros.org/users/39161/ravipr009/) on 2018-12-24**:
Thanks! it works

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-09-09**:
I had this issue in an Rviz panel which cannot own an AsyncSpinner, but the answer was also *THREADS*. The Moveit MotionPlanning plugin has good examples on how to launch threads with `boost::bind`.